# Como puedo hacer para que un estilo css lo detecte en un solo formato (movil o pc)

Tags: php, css

Necesito hacer que un estilo de css quede activo solo cuando abro la web desde un pc de escritorio, tanto en tablets o moviles lo pueda desactivar.

Se que es un atentado a la responsividad, cree un carousel, pero quise comenzar la con la web por la mitad de la imagen. Lo que da un efecto tipo el de la portada de facebook

[image: Asi quedaria]

para esto coloque en el div del carousel:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide altura-carousel" data-ride="carousel">


.altura-carousel{
    height: 300px;
}
```

pero cuando contraigo a dispositivos mas pequeños la altura permanece fija y me deja un vació gris
Entonces quiero saber si puedo establecer parámetros de cuando ese estilo se active

Comment: ¿Por qué no haces un media query para que no lo muestre a partir de X tamaño de pantalla? `@media only screen and (max-width: 1360px) { .carousel { display: none; } }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eso te sirven los media queries en css, para dar estilos dependiendo de la resolución:

Aquí tienes un ejemnplo:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
}
```

Este ejemplo si la resolución del visitante es mayor a 768px se aplicarán los estilos a los elementos que le hayas indicado, en este caso a h1 y a h2.

De esta manera es muy fácil poner estilos diferentes a las distintas resoluciones de los visitantes.

Ahora solo tienes que modificar las clases que quieras dentro de los media queries que personalices

Answer (score 4):

Complementando lo anterior, puedes ser más especifico especificando la orientación del dispositivo, el ancho máximo que puede tener y el mínimo. Aquí abajo te dejo algunos ejemplos.

-- edit

```
@media all and (max-width: 360px) and (orientation: portrait) { 
    /* Tú estilo aquí */
}
@media all and (min-width: 361) and (orientation: landscape) { 
    /* Tú estilo aquí */ 
}
```

Comment: `min-width: 0` y no ponerlo, es lo mismo.

Comment: Gracias, no lo sabia, ahí está editado
;)